# Флаги и манипуляторы форматирования

Tags: c++, потоки-данных, вывод

У меня есть переменная `double d = 12.3321`. Как мне сначала вывести на экран `12.3321`, потом `12.33`, а затем снова `12.3321` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
double d = 12.3321;
cout
    << setprecision(6) << d << endl
    << setprecision(4) << d << endl
    << setprecision(6) << d << endl;
```

См. https://ideone.com/KK1qom

Comment: я думаю имеется в виду, что 1 и последний случай - это поставить по умолчанию точность - например `0.125` чтобы и потом выводилось `0.125`, а не `0.12500`

Comment: @Zhihar Какое ТЗ - такое и ХЗ :) Ответ строго на вопрос, и пусть скажет спасибо, что не написали `cout << "12.3321\n12.33\n12.3321\n";`...\

Comment: да. пожалуй я имел ввиду как вернуть по умолчанию:)@Harry

Comment: @Harry у меня вопрос. Насколько я знаю `setprecision` устанавливает количество знаков после запятой. Но тем не менее в вашем ответе, там где вы указали 4, выводится 2 числа после запятой. как это работает?

Comment: См. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision и https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision - это немного не то, что в `printf` - тут имеется в виду общее количество цифр.

Comment: Только если не установлен `fixed`.

Comment: @EOF Да, спасибо за уточнение.

Comment: всё, разобрался! Всем большое спасибо :)

Comment: Потом бы только не забыть восстановить значение по умолчанию.... (особенно если вывод размазан по нескольким функциям)